# Order of the routes effects the operation

Tags: laravel, routes

```
Route::post('/index','NewleagueController@store')->name('leaguestore');
Route::post('/index','NewleagueController@join')->name('joinleague');
```

I have a table named 'league' and a form that call the first route, which create a new league. The other form, in a different page allows a user to join a league calling the second route.
In the home page I have two buttons that open the first and the second route respectively. 
The problem is that only the route positioned lower (in this case the second route) works fine. 
If I click the button that calls the route positioned higher (the first route in this case), I see the following error:
Route [leaguestore] not defined.

Comment: You're defining the same path twice, that's not possible. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: /index is the path to the home page. I need to go back home in both cases. What can I do?